# Selenium Chromedriver using Python3 - WebDriverException: unable to discover open pages

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

When I run code on a new computer, with `windows7`, using `Python3`, I get an error immediately when calling

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

The error is :

> WebDriverException: unknown error: unable to discover open pages (Driver info: chromedriver=2.4.226107,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)

Any ideas on what may be causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> WebDriverException: unknown error: unable to discover open pages (Driver info: chromedriver=2.4.226107,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)

[This is version incompatibility issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/56). I think you are confusing with chromedriver version. You are  currently using `chromeDriver v2.4` which supports [`Chrome browser from v29 to v32`](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.4/notes.txt) which is very outdated.

To fix this issue you should [download latest chromedriver](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) which is currently [v2.25](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.25) to support latest Chrome browser.